# Installing SSDT on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server Data Tools on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine. I'm getting the following error:

[image: SSDT install error]

I've tried using both the .exe file and the ISO. I'm getting my files from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

What can I do to make SSDT install on my machine?

---

## Edit

This also happens when I try to remove the existing SSDT.

---

## Edit 2

It seems that the problem is with the existing installation of SSDT. The `SSDT.msi` file needed to do changes/removal is missing. The path `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` has been purged, which is where this file should be located.

I have no idea how to remove the existing SSDT now.